# how to make a host in the Lan to forward traffic between other hosts in the same LAN in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, forwarding, traffic

I am setting a test topology in Mininet as the following:

```
sudo mn --mac --topo linear,3  --switch ovsk --controller=remote,ip=10.0.2.15,port=6653
```

like this:
[image: simple topology]
I want the traffic going from H1 to H3 to go visit H2 before being forwarded to H3. I have set flow rules on my switches (Open vSwitch) to do that. 
However, when traffic goes to H2, it gets dropped there.

What configurations I should add to H2 (Ubuntu 14.04) in order to enable H2 to forward a traffic that is not destined to it, nor originated from it?

Comment: What are you using to make the LAN? Mininet? Separate VMs altogether with a switch? Please say. It helps.

Comment: I am using mininet with floodlight SDN controller as follows : sudo mn --mac --topo linear,3  --switch ovsk --controller=remote,ip=10.0.2.15,port=6653

Comment: I am using mininet and floodlight controller , here is my topology: sudo mn --mac --topo linear,3  --switch ovsk --controller=remote,ip=10.0.2.15,port=6653

Answer (score 0):

The feature I think you'll need to enable is **IP Forwarding**.

This can be accessed with the `sysctl` utility:

`sysctl -a | grep forwarding` produces (on my Mac):

```
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 0
net.inet6.ip6.forwarding: 0
```

It may look slightly different on Ubuntu.  The `0` value means IP Forwarding is disabled.

For me to enable IP Forwarding (v4), I would, as root:

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root# sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 0 -> 1
```

This should take effect immediately, however, it will not persist after a reboot.  To make it so, I would place

`net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: Thank you Nevin for your answer, I have activated the forwarding using this command on ubuntu 14.04 : sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  However the traffic is still dropped in the host 2 , I used Tcpdump to see traffic inbound , but there is no outbound traffic from the interface of the host 2.

Comment: Are all the hosts on the same IP network?  If so, H2 would expect that H1 and H3 are speaking directly to each other, and will thus not participate in routing:  Were it to do so, it would be putting duplicate data onto the network.

Please include the routing tables of each host, with `netstat -rn` or similar command.

Comment: Thank you Williams, I finally could do it by rewriting the destination Mac address in the switch. the problem was that , the host 2 drops packets that are not destined to it ( different Mac destination address). thus by rewriting the destination Mac address to host2's Mac address in switch 2, and by activating the IP forwarding in host 2, traffic is successfully redirected.

Comment: Perhaps enabling the NIC's "Promiscuous" mode might keep the packet around long enough to re-forward it...

Comment: Proxy-ARP might be another avenue as well.

Comment: Thank you Williams, how can I use proxy-ARp for the purpose of redirection, could you suggest some reading?

Comment: I searched google for "enabling proxy arp on ubuntu", and got this result:  http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_8.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers, I finally could do it by rewriting the destination Mac address of the packets in the switch. the problem was that , the host 2 drops packets that are not destined to it ( different Mac destination address). thus by rewriting the destination Mac address to host2's Mac address in switch 2, and by activating the IP forwarding in host 2, traffic is successfully redirected. 
so the step one , is to tell S2 to send traffic to Host 2 with destination Mac of host 2.
and step 2, is to tell S2 to rewrite the the Mac address of traffic returning from host 2 to host 3 Mac address ( to restore the original mac address).